# sorting is not working after using .load() list.js & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, list.js

I am using list.min.js for sorting the table column. It works fine till data is not refreshed again from database using .load() method.
But after using .load() method my data successfully loaded but i am not able to sort it again.

Below is my HTML and JavaScript code.

**HTML Code**

```
 <div class="table-responsive table-scrollable" data-toggle="list" data-list-values='["GroupID", "TestGroupName"]'>
              <table class="table align-items-center table-flush table-hover" id="TableTestGroupName">
                <thead class="thead-light sticky-top">
                  <tr>
                    <th class="sort" data-sort="GroupID">Group ID</th>
                    <th class="sort" data-sort="TestGroupName">Test Group Name</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="list">
                  <tr class="lh-6">
                    <td>
                      <span class="GroupID text-muted">Col A 1</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <b class="TestGroupName">Col B 1</b>
                    </td>
                  </tr>   
                  <tr class="lh-6">
                    <td>
                      <span class="GroupID text-muted">Col A 2</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <b class="TestGroupName">Col B 2</b>
                    </td>
                  </tr>                  
                </tbody>
              </table>
       </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#TableTestGroupName tbody').load('<?php echo  base_url()?>TestLibrary_Controller/LoadTestGroup');
        $('#TableTestGroupName tbody').sortable();
```

I have used  `$('#TableTestGroupName tbody').sortable('refresh');` also but its not working.

Please help me.

Comment: Try `.load(url , () => {   // ... refresh the sortable on load callback function  })`

Comment: HI now its resolved using above code. Thanks Mohamed, But when i am doing sorting its show previous data not the ajax loaded content. I guess i need to re initialize the list but how to do ? Can you help ?